# Adding Custom GridView to Control collection

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a custom GridView control in my site, basically just a class extending GridView as

```
    ITCSGridView : GridView
```

This has caused a bug in the export to excel feature which is adding the control to a table cell and then exporting it. The line the error occurs on is:

```
    NewTableCell(ATable).Controls.Add(AControl);
```

And the exception thrown is:

```
    The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).
```

Prior to me extending the GridView control, the export function was working. The only way I have found to get it to work is to pass the first child control of the custom GridView (which is of type System.Web.UI.WebControl.ChildTable) but then I lose the styling which is required.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Additional code added below

The custom GridView class

```
    public class ITCSGridView : GridView
    {
        private const string ControlHeaderBackColor = "#B0E0E6";
        private const string ControlHeaderForeColor = "#000000";
        private const string ControlSelectedRowStyleForeColor = "#335555";

        public ITCSGridView() : base()
        {
            ControlProperties();
            HeaderProperties();
            PagerProperties();
            RowProperties();
        }

        private void ControlProperties()
        {
            EnableTheming = true;
            Width = new Unit("100%");
            SkinID = "ITCSGridView";
            CellPadding = 2;
            BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
            HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
            AllowSorting = true;
        }

        private void HeaderProperties()
        {
            HeaderStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
            HeaderStyle.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(ControlHeaderBackColor);
            HeaderStyle.ForeColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(ControlHeaderForeColor);
            HeaderStyle.Font.Bold = false;
        }

        private void PagerProperties()
        {
            AllowPaging = true;
            PageSize = SASMisc.DDLGridViewPageSize;
            PagerSettings.Position = PagerPosition.TopAndBottom;
            PagerSettings.Mode = PagerButtons.NumericFirstLast;
            PagerSettings.FirstPageText = "First";
            PagerSettings.LastPageText = "Last";
        }

        private void RowProperties()
        {
            RowStyle.Wrap = false;
            SelectedRowStyle.ForeColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(ControlSelectedRowStyleForeColor);
            SelectedRowStyle.Font.Bold = false;
        }
```

Within the class that handles exporting the control to Excel, a System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table Control is created and the GridView control is added to a TableCell within the Table Control, the call to NewTableCell(ATable) is the method that returns the System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell. This is basically just:

```
    // The GridView control is passed directly to this method from the aspx.cs
    private void AddControlToTable(System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table ATable, Control AControl){
        var Table = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table();
        // Excpetion thrown on line below (this works when using standard GridView instead of custom extended)
        NewTableCell(ATable).Controls.Add(AControl);
    }

    private TableCell NewTableCell(System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table ATable)
    {
        TableCell Lcell = new TableCell();
        TableRow LRow = new TableRow();
        LRow.Cells.Add(Lcell);
        ATable.Rows.Add(LRow);
        return Lcell;
    } // private TableCell AddToTable(Table ATable)
```

Comment: And the NewTableCell(ATable).Controls.Add(AControl); happens in your new class ?

Comment: No the Custom GridView control is passed to an export class, that line of code is within the export class.

Comment: I've added the custom GridView code and explained the export code a bit better, let me know if you think more is required please.

Comment: Matthew - I'm still missing the code pieces around the export logic.

Comment: I've added some more of the code, there are a few other lines of code in the AddControlsToTable method but they are not executed in this isntance. The AddControlsToTable method is called immediately within the export class and so fails very early on.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have on the same page/or control included on the page piece of markup in which you're doing this:

```
<%= DateTime.Now %>
```

The `DateTime.Now` is just for illustration - the `<%= %>` matters. This screws up control tree & makes dynamical adding of controls (as you're doing impossible). Workaround is simple - enclose all `<%= %>` statements into `runat="server"` control - best control for this is placeholder.

So `<%= DateTime.Now %>` becomes

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
  <%= DateTime.Now %>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Control tree is consistent and you can add controls dynamically from codebehind once more.

Comment: There is markup throughout the website like that and it would be possible for me to change them all, I'm still a bit confused however as to why it is happening, if I change the reference in the aspx back to standard GridView it works again. There are no code blocks like that in the control as it is only made up of a cs class.